# What series does Mathematica use for Hypergeometric1F1?

Tags: special-functions, series-expansion

I'm trying to get an analytical expression for

```
Hypergeometric1F1[-a, 1/2, X]
```

Provided `a` is an integer number. I tried adding that assumption:

```
Simplify[Hypergeometric1F1[-a, 1/2, X], Assumptions -> Element[a, Integers]]
```

But it does nothing. If I plug in any particular `a`, it however instantly returns an answer, so some kind of explicit series definitely exists.

```
Hypergeometric1F1[1/2 - a/2, 3/2, -X] /. a -> 9
```

$1+\frac{8X}{3}+\frac{8X^2}{5}+\frac{32X^3}{105}+\frac{16X^4}{945}$

How do I find out the formula that Mathematica uses to produce this answer?

I can find similar situations like `Gamma[1/2 + a]` when Mathematica uses the expression, but I don't know how to reveal it. I can surely use math books for `Gamma`, but `Hypergeometric1F1` is harder to find. Besides, why look for anything when it already exists in the system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
expr = Hypergeometric1F1[-a, 1/2, x];
```

Use [`SeriesCoefficient`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SeriesCoefficient.html) to find the coefficient in the series expansion

```
c[n_] = SeriesCoefficient[expr, {x, 0, n}]
```

[image]

Verifying that the infinite sum is the original expression

```
Sum[c[n]*x^n, {n, 0, Infinity}] == expr

(* True *)
```

As shown in the documentation for [`Hypergeometric1F1`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hypergeometric1F1.html), the series expansion is

```
Sum[Pochhammer[a, n]/Pochhammer[b, n] * z^n/n!, {n, 0, Infinity}]

(* Hypergeometric1F1[a, b, z] *)
```

or, for your specific case,

```
Sum[Pochhammer[-a, n]/Pochhammer[1/2, n] * x^n/n!, {n, 0, Infinity}] == expr

(* True *)
```

Answer (score 9):

Recall that $(-n)_k=0$ for $k>n, n,k\in\mathbb N$. Thus, what you have is an appropriate truncation of the usual series for the Kummer function.

```
With[{a = 9}, 
     Sum[Pochhammer[1/2 - a/2, k] (-x)^k/(Pochhammer[3/2, k] k!), {k, 0, a/2 - 1/2}]]
   1 + (8 x)/3 + (8 x^2)/5 + (32 x^3)/105 + (16 x^4)/945
```